# NPM and Yarn Registry issues while creating react app

Tags: reactjs

When creating react app using `create-react-app my-app` it results with npm and yarn registry errors. I have tried to re-install node and set registry path as well but no luck. Please suggest a solution

```
C:\Users\malliswarit\Desktop>create-react-app my-app

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\malliswarit\Desktop\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

yarn add v1.9.4
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning react-scripts > autoprefixer > browserslist@2.11.3: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
warning react-scripts > babel-preset-react-app > babel-preset-env > browserslist@2.11.3: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
warning react-scripts > css-loader > cssnano > autoprefixer > browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
warning react-scripts > css-loader > cssnano > postcss-merge-rules > browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
warning react-scripts > jest > jest-cli > istanbul-api > istanbul-lib-hook@1.2.1: 1.2.0 should have been a major version bump
warning react-scripts > css-loader > cssnano > postcss-merge-rules > caniuse-api > browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.npmjs.org/react-dev-utils/-/react-dev-utils-5.0.2.tgz: Request failed \"404 Not Found\"".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "C:\\Users\\malliswarit\\Desktop\\my-app\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts --cwd C:\Users\malliswarit\Desktop\my-app has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn-error.log
Deleting my-app / from C:\Users\malliswarit\Desktop
Done.
```

Comment: Are you using a proxy or firewall?

Comment: Iam using corporate firewall.

Comment: This seems to be the problem.

Comment: Any solution please. It used to work prior to afternoon. Its not working after many trails.

Comment: If it's a firewall issue, then you have to find a way through your firewall. Talk to your network administrators.

Comment: Seems not an issue with firewall. As per network team its working fine and not blocking any ports or service calls.

Answer (score 3):

`npm uninstall -g create-react-app`

`npm uninstall -g yarn`

`npm cache clean --force`

`npm install -g create-react-app`

`create-react-app cool-projecy-name`

Not sure if the uninstall of create-react-app and cache clean is needed but this is what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Below are the steps done to resolve this issue.

1. `npm install -g react-dev-utils@https://registry.npmjs.org/react-dev-utils/react-dev-utils-5.0.2.tgz`
2. delete .npmrc and then run
3. `yarn config set strict-ssl false`
4. `create-react-app my-app`

Issue resolved. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Try `yarn add` with the package URL without -/ and then run `create-react-app my-app`:

```
yarn add https://registry.yarnpkg.com/react-dev-utils/react-dev-utils-5.0.2.tgz
```

or if using npm try:

```
npm install -g react-dev-utils@https://registry.npmjs.org/react-dev-utils/react-dev-utils-5.0.2.tgz
```

For reference, [yarn add](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add)

Comment: No Luck still same error after installing dev utils@ registry.

Comment: The error occurred when the invalid URL was hit while installing the package. If you have managed to get the **react-dev-utils** package installed, then it won't the hit the URL again and hence the error won't come up again.